# MySQL INNER JOIN - '=' vs 'like'

Tags: mysql, activerecord, inner-join

We're having some odd issues with MySQL inner joins.  Basically, we get an odd error when using an '=' operator but using 'like' instead makes it work.  Unfortunately, this is via ActiveRecord and no easy way to just slap 'like' in there instead, plus we want to understand what's actually happening here.

Here is the query that fails:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `versions` INNER JOIN `site_versions`
              ON `versions`.id = `site_versions`.version_id;
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR 1296 (HY000): Got error 20008 'Query aborted due to out of query memory'
from NDBCLUSTER
```

Here is the query that works:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `versions` INNER JOIN `site_versions`
              ON `versions`.id like `site_versions`.version_id;
```

Here are some details on the tables themselves:

```
mysql> desc site_versions;
+----------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version_id           | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
[..snip..]
+----------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> desc versions;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
[..snip..]
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Any ideas why the 'like' works and the '=' does not?

Comment: is the like actually giving results you expect?  maybe it's just failing to join anything (because what does like mean for ints?) and so avoiding the memory problem that the valid query is triggering.

Comment: @andrewcooke - Hmm, `like` does seem to work when used that way: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86792/1

Comment: It might also help the question to show the `explain` of each query.

Comment: I think you need to include info on the database engine for the tables. Strings comparison differs greatly between the different options.

Comment: @andrewcooke Yes it does return valid results.

Comment: This is using NDB/CLUSTER database engine.  I don't have the explain, but I can probably dig it up.

Comment: what does it (the like) mean?  does it coerce the ints to strings before comparing?  is that breaking indexing?  i guess this is why people are asking for explains?

Comment: `LIKE` forces `site_versions` to be leading. Could you please run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM site_versions STRAIGHT_JOIN versions ON versions.id = site_versions.version_id`?

Comment: It seems to me that the query you have itsn't that informative it should only give you the count of site_versions where the version_id is not null, so there is no need for the join.  Could you explain what you want know from the data?

Answer (score 3):

Ironically this seems to be related to optimizations; by using `LIKE` you force MySQL to stop using possible indexes (at least with number columns, because it has to cast them all to string for the comparison).

So by using `=` it seems that MySQL simply runs out of space (memory / disc) to use the index (check the `key_buffer` setting).

Of course, this is just a hunch and I don't know much about NDB to help you further, but I hope this moves you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine how `like` works well in this situation, but how about just trying to check out the value of variable `MaxAllocate` and increase it? Its default value is `32M` and can be increased up to `1G`.

Reference : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html#ndbparam-ndbd-maxallocate

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix your problem, but it's possible.  Don't use `count(*)`. Maybe it's getting 'confused' about what to count.  It's best-practice to count a specific field e.g. `id`.  To do this, you need to use an alias for the tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(v.id) FROM versions as v
INNER JOIN site_versions as sv ON v.id = sv.version_id;
```

Comment: Or just use a constant: `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ...`

Comment: In an unusual situation like the OP's one must not be too much surprised at suggestions like yours. And I won't be. But this statement, *‘It's best-practice to count a specific field’*, made in the context of the other one, namely *‘Don't use `count(*)`’*, sounds like a general advice for the future and as such is arguable, to say the least. Using `COUNT(*)` to count rows in a group regardless of the data in the rows or of any other condition is perfectly valid and according to the standard. Maybe there are some implications to it in MySQL, but then you might have to mention that it was so.

Comment: @Andriy - I also always assumed `count(*)` should be avoided when possible? Although the syntax is valid and maybe not related to op's issue, there is indeed [a notable difference performance wise](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/).  I am not DBA though, but as developper have always avoided `count(*)` when possible because of this. I may have misunderstood something here, please clue me in if I did.

Comment: @stefgosselin there's a difference alright; in the link you posted `count(*)` outperforms a `count()` on a nullable column :)

Comment: @stefgosselin: Well, the article does demonstrate the difference in performance between `count(*)` and `count(col)` and the difference seems to be in favour of `count(*)`, unless it is me who is missing something. So, as a developer, you might want to be interested in using more efficient constructs, and therefore my question is, why avoid `count(*)`?

Comment: @jack @Andriy - Yes, I realise after re-reading closely *my own link* count(*) is indeed faster... <sheepish grin>. I had always used `count()` in the same manner as `select()`, avoiding when possible the `*`.  Funny thing is, after all those years in 3 different dev teams and many code reviews, I am amazed this was never caught, though to be fair I did a lot of frontend stuff. Thanks guys, love this site, really appreciate your replies.